# Escaping The Broken Time-Machine

Tags: riddle, word

Alexis is time-traveling inside an elevator-sized time machine into December 14th, 1977 from June 2nd, 2700 when the time machine halted, abruptly.

Alex started tensing. She rummaged through her bag, trying to find her inter-stellar communication device, but, mysteriously, it was not there. Instead, she only found a couple of coins, a wrench, a hairbrush, a screwdriver, and a pack of dry cells. She looked around and saw fire hydrant, a couple of buttons, and something like a battery holder unit.

Alex was in deep thinking when suddenly, there was a large beep, and following the beep a scratchy voice muttered a long list of letters, in this order:

> O S M O W D I T J D C M H M B J M D A O T J M T D E J R O I J E D S

A few seconds later, a sweet woman's voice shouted what sounded like:

> Bctoeor Amy Cebrmdee Uljy ....Scrambled....Remove....Letters....First....Voice....

What should Alex do?

Comment: Hey @CYr, welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Comment: I like the idea that someone from the year 2700 still has a phone :)  Great puzzle too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bctoeor Amy Cebrmdee Uljy .... Scrambled.... Remove.... Letters.... First.... Voice....

> This unscrambles to October May December July. If we remove the letters O,M,D,J from the first voice’s letters, we get S W I T C H B A T T E R I E S.

This says:

> Switch Batteries. She should therefore switch the batteries (ie. put some of the dry cell batteries into the machine’s battery holder).

Note:

> Edit came at 2:11pm, 7/14/2020, after OP deleted the extra C from the puzzle. Great first puzzle, OP! Welcome to Puzzling.SE!